# mysql how to update a column of all rows and for each row a different column value

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, sql-update

Here is a sample table:

```
id   name   code
----------------
1    n1     
2    n2    
3    n3
```

I want to update the code column of every row with different values, so for row of id 1 i want to add this value for code 'zb6DXBfJ', and for row id 2 'NV6Nx4St', and for row id 3 this value for code column 'q23ZMACc'.  So my final table should look like this:

```
id   name   code
----------------
1    n1     zb6DXBfJ
2    n2     NV6Nx4St
3    n3     q23ZMACc
```

Comment: Are you asking for the SQL to do that?  Have you tried something?  This is just writing a few update statements. Shouldn't be too hard to figure out.

Comment: except the actual table im trying to modify has over 100 rows that need to be updated...this is just a sample

Comment: Is there some way of calculating this code for each row?

Comment: @dave: Looks like your question wasn't clear, as you can see from the answers you got. :)

Comment: @celticminstrel how can i do that?

Comment: Um, that was supposed to be me asking you how you get the code for each row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE TableName 
 SET Code = CASE 
                 WHEN id = 1 THEN 'zb6DXBfJ'
                 WHEN id = 2 THEN 'NV6Nx4St'
                 WHEN id = 3 THEN 'q23ZMACc'
            END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UPDATE Table_Name WHERE id = desired_id SET code = desired_code;
```

Of course, you'll need to substitute Table_Name, desired_id, and desired_code as required.

Comment: Well I'm not really sure what you want to be done then. Your original question seems a little too vague. So you want every id in your table to get its own code value, right? Do you already have stored somewhere a relation between id and code?

Comment: hows it vague?  i mean i gave how the table looks in the beginning and how i wanted to it look...i don't understand how anyone can get it confused...

Comment: You haven't specified what you really want to do. Yes, you have a table with missing code elements. You add missing elements to a table by updating it. Whether you do it in one query or multiple doesn't really matter. In each case you will still have to manually enter what you want to enter as code, unless you have a relationship between id and code already defined somewhere, which you did not mention.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where your codes come from, you can try one of the folowing:

If your codes came from another table, you can create a procedure that will "match" each line of the two table in order to update the codes. Here's an example :

First create the tables (the one you already have, and the one with the codes)

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
code VARCHAR(300));

CREATE TABLE table2 (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY,
code VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO table1 (id, name) VALUES
(1, 'n1'),
(2, 'n2'),
(3, 'n3');

INSERT INTO table2 (id, code) VALUES
(1, 'zb6DXBfJ'),
(2, 'NV6Nx4St'),
(3, 'q23ZMACc');
```

Then create the actual procedure

```
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE assign_strings()

BEGIN

    DECLARE _id INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE str VARCHAR(300);
    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT id FROM table1;

    open cur;
    myloop:LOOP
        fetch cur into _id;

        SELECT code INTO str FROM table2 WHERE id = _id;
        UPDATE table1 SET code = str WHERE id = _id;

    end loop myloop;
    close cur;


END //
delimiter ;
```

You can now call the procedure

```
CALL assign_strings();
```

Note that I don't know your logic to retrieve these code. Here I just assume table2.id has the code for table1.id. Its a little dumb but your logic may be more complicated.

If your codes are just random strings (non-unique) you can just use a function instead of a procedure like this :

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION get_random_string()
  RETURNS VARCHAR(300)
BEGIN
  RETURN 'Your_random_string';
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Note that you'll need to implement your own random string strategy. You can use something like a MD5 function with a random number and substrings... whatever you need.

You can now call this function directly in an update statement like so :

```
UPDATE table1 set code = get_random_string();
```

Hope it gets you started.